# How to change a property in a CSS animation abruptly without animating

Tags: css, css-animations

Here is what I am trying to figure out, but without using the 51% keyframe as a hacky way to implement the change of `transform-origin`. Here is a [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p7pswnpq/).

```css
@keyframes spin {
  0% { 
    transform-origin: 50% 0; 
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(0deg) translateZ(0px); 
  }
  50% { 
    transform-origin: 50% 0; 
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(360deg) translateZ(0px); 
  } 
  51% { 
    transform-origin: 50% 100%; /* hacky way to instantly change transform-origin */ 
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: 50% 100%; 
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(0deg) translateZ(0px); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: How about something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p7pswnpq/2/) using two animations and a `steps` function for the origin animation? I don't think it is possible with just one.

Comment: Why would that be considered hacky?

Comment: @Harry Thanks! That's just what I was looking for!

[Louis, I'd consider it hacky because it's a work-around not a solution]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I had mentioned in my comment, there is ***no way to achieve this with just a single animation***. I wouldn't call your original approach as *hacky* because a sudden change means the addition of a new keyframe immediately after the previous one (50% and 51%) but I kind of get what you mean to say.

One possible alternate is to ***make use of two animations*** - one for the transform and the other for the transform-origin change. Here we can make the second animation (the transform-origin change) alone have  a `steps` (or `step-end`) timing function so that this change alone happens abruptly.

(***Note:*** I'm providing this option just as an answer to your question. I'd still prefer the earlier approach and avoid having two different keyframe rules to perform the same animation.)

Below is a sample snippet:

```css
.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
  animation: spin 4s linear infinite, origin 4s step-end infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(0deg) translateZ(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(360deg) translateZ(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateX(0deg) translateZ(0px);
  }
}
@keyframes origin {
  50% {
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="http://makeameme.org/media/templates/120/grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120">
```