# Css-only countdown cant keep the digits work together

Tags: css

I am trying to build a programmable css only countdown. Tens of the second is working good but ones of it is not working as I expected.

```css
*:after{
 animation-direction: reverse;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.secondsTen:after{
 content:'';
 animation-name: tenBased;
 animation-duration: 10s;
}

.secondsSix:after{
 content:'';
 animation-name: sixBased;
 animation-duration: 60s;
}

@keyframes tenBased {
 0% { content: '0';}
 10% { content: '1';}
 20% { content: '2';}
 30% { content: '3';}
 40% { content: '4';}
 50% { content: '5';}
 60% { content: '6';}
 70% { content: '7';}
 80% { content: '8';}
 90% { content: '9';}
 100% { content: '0';}
}

@keyframes sixBased {
  0% {content: '0';}
  16.66667% {content: '1';}
  33.33333% {content: '2';}
  50% {content: '3';}
  66.66667% {content: '4';}
  83.33333% {content: '5';}
  100% {content: '0';}
}
```

```html
<span class='secondsSix'></span>
<span class='secondsTen'></span>
```

As you can see, ones of the second is decreasing after 5 seconds. But it supposed to decrease after 10 seconds to 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation of the observed behaviour

The keyframe animation performs a transition between the given states. In your example you animate the value of the `content` property of a pseudo-element which is totally valid but you have to keep in mind that there are no intermediate steps between two keyframes that can be visualized in this case.

So in fact, the transition from `100% {content: '0';}` to `83.33333% {content: '5';}` will end after 10 seconds (as expected) but *at some point in between* the value of the property changes. When setting `animation-timing-function: linear;` it's exactly between the two keyframes - after 5 seconds in this example what makes it look like it starts with a delay.

```css
*:after{
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.secondsSix:after{
  content:'';
  animation-name: sixBased;
  animation-duration: 60s;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes sixBased {
  0% {content: '0'; left: 100%}
  16.66667% {content: '1';}
  33.33333% {content: '2';}
  50% {content: '3';}
  66.66667% {content: '4';}
  83.33333% {content: '5';}
  100% {content: '0'; left: 0%}
}

.timeline {
  border: solid grey;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 2em;
}

.timeline span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8.33%;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='secondsSix'></div>
<div class='timeline'>
  <span>0</span><span>5</span><span>10</span><span>15</span><span>20</span><span>25</span>
  <span>30</span><span>35</span><span>40</span><span>45</span><span>50</span><span>55</span>
</div>
```

I've analyzed the behaviour with the help of the above snippet and had a look at what will happen if I remove individual keyframes (one at a time, represented by a gap in the following table).

```
Content 0   5   4   3   2   1   0
Time    0   5   15  25  35  45  55
Time    0       10  25  35  45  55
Time    0   5       20  35  45  55
Time    0   5   15      30  45  55 // change from '4' to '2' at second 30
Time    0   5   15  25      40  55
Time    0   5   15  25  35      50
```

As you can see, the content always changes exactly between two given keyframes.
The same can be observed in the following demo where I've modified your tenBase animation:

```css
*:after {
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

.secondsTen:after {
  content: '';
  animation-name: tenBased;
}

.secondsTenTwoSteps:after {
  content: '';
  animation-name: tenBasedTwoSteps;
}

@keyframes tenBased {
  0% { content: '0' }
  10% { content: '1'; }
  20% { content: '2'; }
  30% { content: '3'; }
  40% { content: '4'; }
  50% { content: '5'; }
  60% { content: '6'; }
  70% { content: '7'; }
  80% { content: '8'; }
  90% { content: '9'; }
  100% { content: '10' }
}

@keyframes tenBasedTwoSteps {
  0% { content: '0' }
  100% { content: '10' }
}
```

```html
<div class='secondsTen'></div>
<div class='secondsTenTwoSteps'></div>
```

---

### Solution #1

The first way of solving the problem is simple but not very beautiful. What you want is to [change a property in a CSS animation abruptly without animating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41801802/3162554) and what the OP describes as *hacky way* in the linked question would look like this:

```css
*:after{
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.secondsSix:after{
  content:'';
  animation-name: sixBased;
  animation-duration: 60s;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes sixBased {
  0% {content: '0'; left: 100%}
  0.1% {content: '0';}
  16.66667% {content: '1';}
  16.7% {content: '1';}
  33.3% {content: '2';}
  33.33333% {content: '2';}
  33.4% {content: '3';}
  50% {content: '3';}
  50.1% {content: '4';}
  66.66667% {content: '4';}
  66.7% {content: '5';}
  83.33333% {content: '5';}
  83.4% {content: '0';}
  100% {content: '0'; left: 0%}
}

.timeline {
  border: solid grey;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 2em;
}

.timeline span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8.33%;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='secondsSix'></div>
<div class='timeline'>
  <span>0</span><span>5</span><span>10</span><span>15</span><span>20</span><span>25</span>
  <span>30</span><span>35</span><span>40</span><span>45</span><span>50</span><span>55</span>
</div>
```

---

### Solution #2

There is also another solution. You'll see that changing `animation-timing-function: linear;` to something else like `animation-timing-function: ease-out;` changes the point in time when the content acutally changes. We have observed that the content changes exactly in the middle when using a linear timing function, so I assume that it will change on 50% of progress between two keyframes.

As it is allowed to define a [`cubic-bezier`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/single-transition-timing-function#The_cubic-bezier()_class_of_timing-functions) we can shift this point in time where the progress becomes 50% close to the end. Keep in mind that your animation-direction is reversed so you have to mirror the curve (see [cubic-bezier.com/#0,1,0,1](http://cubic-bezier.com/#0,1,0,1)).

```css
*:after{
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
}

.secondsSix:after{
  content:'';
  animation-name: sixBased;
  animation-duration: 60s;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes sixBased {
  0% {content: '0'; left: 100%}
  16.66667% {content: '1'; animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0,1,0,1);}
  33.33333% {content: '2'; animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0,1,0,1);}
  50% {content: '3'; animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0,1,0,1);}
  66.66667% {content: '4'; animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0,1,0,1);}
  83.33333% {content: '5'; animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0,1,0,1);}
  100% {content: '0'; left: 0%}
}

.timeline {
  border: solid grey;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 2em;
}

.timeline span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8.33%;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='secondsSix'></div>
<div class='timeline'>
  <span>0</span><span>5</span><span>10</span><span>15</span><span>20</span><span>25</span>
  <span>30</span><span>35</span><span>40</span><span>45</span><span>50</span><span>55</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You are welcome. It was fun to dig deeper into this and I've learned a little bit about the cubic-bezier as well :)

Comment: After looking more into your solution it seems lot more acceptable. Great approach and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to try this

```css
.secondsTen:before {
    content: '9876543210';
    width:1ch;
    overflow:hidden;
    animation:tenBased 10s steps(10) infinite;
    float:left;
}
.secondsSix:before{
    content: '543210';
    width:1ch;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    animation:sixBased 60s steps(6) infinite;
}
@keyframes tenBased {
    0% {text-indent:0}
    100% {text-indent:-10ch;}
}
@keyframes sixBased {
    0% {text-indent:0}
    100% {text-indent:-6ch;}
}
```

```html
<span class='secondsSix'></span>
<span class='secondsTen'></span>
```

Comment: As I changed my structure to your, I want to accept this as answer. But @Marvin answer was lot more informative btw.